# Creating an array from JSON data in GAS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-apps-script

I am trying to make an array like `value1,value2,value3` that I can iterate through later.

I have the following so far:

```
var url = 'URL_STRING';

var headers = {
    headers: {
        Username: 'USERNAME',
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + 'KEY'
    },
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, headers);
var json = response.getContentText();

var obj = JSON.parse(json);
var audits = obj.audits;
Logger.log(audits)
```

The log shows:

```
[{
    id = value1
}, {
    id = value2
}, {
    id = value3
}]
```

I thought I would be able to do something like `var arr[] = obj.audits.id` but this does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const audits =[{
id : "value1"
}, {
id : "value2"
}, {
id : "value3"
}];

const arr = audits.map(({id:v})=>v);
console.log(arr);
```